# Implicitly converting an object of one class to another

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, reference

I have the following working example, where I am passing an object of type `Derived` to a constructor that expects an object of type `Bridge`:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base() {};
    virtual Base* clone() const = 0;
    virtual ~Base() {};
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {};
    virtual Base* clone() const {
        std::cout << "Cloned derived\n";
        return new Derived(*this);
    }
    virtual ~Derived() {}
};

class Bridge {
public:
    Bridge(const Base& b_) {
        b = b_.clone();
        std::cout << "Cloned b\n";
    };
    ~Bridge() {}
private:
    Base *b;
};

class Test {
public:
    Test(const Bridge& b_) : b(b_) {};
    
private:
    Bridge b;
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    Test t(d);
}
```

Why is this allowed? From what I can gather it works because of `Bridge`'s constructor that takes a reference to a `Base` object. But I have a hard time figuring out what the order actually is.

Is the following timeline of what goes on correct?

1. The statement `Test t(d);` implies we have `Bridge& b_(d)` (as per `Test`'s constructor)
2. `Test`'s constructor creates a new object which is the one that `b` in `Test` is ultimately set to?

Comment: What is a _MWE_ please?

Comment: Minimal Working Example. I will write it out

Comment: The better known acronym here is MCVE ([mcve]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost.

Test expects Bridge and there is a Bridge constructor which accepts Base and Derived publically inherits from Base. So a *temporary* object of type Bridge is created using `d` and this is used to construct `t`.

But this happens in `main` not in the Test constructor. Further this temporary object is destroyed at the end of the `Test t(d);` statement. However by this point you have *copied* the temporary object in your Test constructor so everything seems to be OK (apart from the memory leaks).

Comment: Wouldn't I technically get the same result if I changed `Test(const Bridge& b_)` to `Test(const Base& b_)`? This is equivalent in our example, right?

Comment: @TylerD You would avoid creating and copying the temporary Bridge object that way. Apart from that the end result would be the same.

Comment: I noticed your comment on the memory leaks - where does this occur in the code?

Comment: @TylerD `Derived::clone` allocates memory which is never freed.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding `delete b;` to the destructor of `Bridge`, but that gave me an error (?)

Comment: @Tyler Probably a double delete caused by not following the [rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Very important knowledge to have.